# How can I reference a single table multiple times in the same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Sometimes I need to treat the same table as two separate tables. What is the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an alias like a variable name in your SQL:

```
select
    A.Id,
    A.Name,
    B.Id as SpouseId,
    B.Name as SpouseName
from
    People A
    join People B on A.Spouse = B.id
```

Answer (score 10):

You can reference, just be sure to use a table alias

```
select a.EmployeeName,b.EmployeeName as Manager
from Employees A
join Employees B on a.Mgr_id=B.Id
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an alias:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col3
FROM tbl t1
INNER JOIN tbl t2
    ON t1.col1 = t2.col2
```

Answer (score 2):

Alias is the most obvious solution

```
SELECT * FROM x1 AS x,y1 AS y
```

However if the table is the result of a query a common table expressions is quite usefull

```
;WITH ctx AS 
( select * from z)
SELECT y.* FROM ctx AS c1,ctx AS c2
```

A third solution -- suitable when your query lasts a long time -- is temporary tables:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #monkey
FROM chimpanzee

SELECT * FROM #monkey m1,#monkey m2

DROP TABLE #MONKEY
```

Note a common table expression is only available for one query (the query directly after it), and temporary tables last for the whole batch.

Comment: in your first example, you use the old join syntax: `SELECT * FROM x1 AS x,y1 AS y` it is much better to use the current join syntax: `SELECT * FROM x1 AS x INNER JOIN y1 AS y ON ....`

Comment: I'd have given you an upvote but bot when you use the old implicit join syntax in your examples as that is a very poor programming practice. Plus you are showing cross joins which I doubt the user wants and these types of accidental cross joins are one of the reason why this syntax was replaced 18 years ago with the explicit join syntax.

Comment: The code snippets above are just to illustrate the issue at hand.